# Turning a 2d array from top down to left right

Tags: arrays, lua, 2d

So I made a script to create a 8*4 2d array which worked great but I can't figure out a way to make it from left to right instead of top to bottom. Here's what I mean :

Currently :

[image]

What I want is that the numbers go from left to right instead of up to down. The numbers are represented by u in my code.

```
for i=0,7 do
  for j=0,3 do
      local u = i*4+j+1
  end
end
```

Comment: there is no top down or left to right in your code. you just create a few numbers. so the relevant part is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just rearrange your loops slightly:

```
for i = 0, 3 do                       
    for j = 0, 7 do
         local u = i * 8 + j + 1
         print( i + 1, j + 1, u )  -- for debugging
         -- use value of u in grid square at row (i + 1 ) and column (j + 1 )
    end
end
```

This will output:

```
1   1   1
1   2   2
...
1   8   8
2   1   9
2   2   10
...
4   8   32
```

In other words, the values for the top row are produced first, left to right.  Next the second row, and so on.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you I tried doing that but I realized that I forgot rearranging the position for my tiles. Thanks anyway!